# Will the DataStax Cluster class ever refresh IP address from the hostname given to builder.addContactPoint() if DNS changes?

Tags: dns, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

I've a problem, once set host name, cluster wouldn't update it's IP, even in DNS changes.
Or what is the recommended way of making the application resilient to the fact that more nodes can be added to DNS round robin and old nodes decomissioned ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same thing with Astyanax driver. For me it looks like it works this way:

- DNS name is used only when initial connection to cluster is created. At this point driver collects data about cluster nodes. This information is kept in terms of IP addresses already and DNS names are not used any more. Sub-sequential changes in the cluster topology are propagated into the client also using IP addresses.

So, when you add more nodes to the cluster, you actually do not have to assign domain names to them. Just adding a node to the cluster propagates its IP address to the cluster topology table and this info is distributed among all cluster members and smart clients like Java Driver (some third party clients might not have this info and will use only seed nodes to pass queries to).
When you decommission node it works same way. Just all cluster nodes and smart clients receive information that node with a particular IP is not in the cluster any more. It can be even initial seed node.

->Domain name makes sense only for clients which hadn't established cluster connection.

In case you really need to switch IP you have to:

- Join node with new IP
- Decommission node with old IP
- Assign DNS name to new IP